# AngularJS is stripping keys from my schema object

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongoose

**EDIT: This is not a server-side problem. Please read the question carefully.**

I am building a solution using Mongoose, Express, Node, and Angular. I am attempting to send my Mongoose schema file client side to be parsed. I have successfully acquired the data in an object in my controller script (client side,) structured like so:

```
{
    href: {type: String},
    text: {type: String, trim:true},
    dropdown: {type: Boolean},
    dropdownList: {type: Array}
}
```

This is passed through `$scope.$apply` (because it is being recieved in a callback,) and it is recieved in the HTML like this:

```
{
    href: {},
    text: {trim:true},
    dropdown: {},
    dropdownList: {}
}
```

Having the data types is extremely important for my implementation. Any thoughts?

Comment: type: is mongoose internal use as far as i noticed. but its not valid json. no such thing like String, Boolean, Array in json, but it is javascript.

Comment: I did do some research, and I know it's not valid JSON, but this is already loaded as a Javascript object, which IS valid. I believe that something is happening in transport from my controller code to the html through Angular that is removing the keys.

Comment: its expressjs call to JSON.stringify, who removing it, I believe. you can replace it with your own and use res.send instead of res.json

Comment: No, as I said, I have the complete object already in client side javascript. The issue is not with Express.

Comment: how do you send schema from server to client? not with express? not with res.json?

Comment: ok, you are not sending schema from server, you copy, pasted as client code, I see xD. you can actual send from server though, but anyway, not very good for security then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about monkey patching function object you can do this way.

Add following anywhere before your res.json code run in server or even in client browser.

```
Function.prototype.toJSON = function() { return this.name; }
```

Test with node

```
# node

> var schema = {
...     href: {type: String},
...     text: {type: String, trim:true},
...     dropdown: {type: Boolean},
...     dropdownList: {type: Array}
... }
undefined

> schema
{ href: { type: [Function: String] },
  text: { type: [Function: String], trim: true },
  dropdown: { type: [Function: Boolean] },
  dropdownList: { type: [Function: Array] } }

> JSON.stringify(schema)
'{"href":{},"text":{"trim":true},"dropdown":{},"dropdownList":{}}'

> Function.prototype.toJSON = function() { return this.name; }
[Function]

> JSON.stringify(schema)
'{"href":{"type":"String"},"text":{"type":"String","trim":true},"dropdown":{"type":"Boolean"},"dropdownList":{"type":"Array"}}'
>
```

Comment: This might be rather useful! Thanks! I'll select this as the answer if I can't find anything, but as I illustrated earlier, the issue is not server side. I have successfully gotten the schema object into my clientside controller script for Angular. The type key is being removed when moving from controller script to DOM using angular notation syntax `{{}}`.

Comment: its javascript, so you can use in client too

Comment: That's a good point. If noone comes up with anything else after I eat lunch, I'll use this.

Answer (score 0):

in your object your trying to assign something like `String`, `Array`, `Boolean`.. and note that **those values are not string values** these are only keywords. if u have numbers you can do like this, so you need to use those values as `string values`

```
{
    href: {type: 'String'},
    text: {type: 'String', trim:true},
    dropdown: {type: 'Boolean'},
    dropdownList: {type: 'Array'}
};
```

here is a [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/7zPNtXyQ5eD7EhRLsfzX?p=preview)

Comment: Nice suggestion, but this isn't appropriate for my use as the data can't really be modified. Mongoose needs to parse the data in its current form, and I can't change that.